# Perlin noise and heightmaps/bitmaps

Tags: c++, c, bitmap, terrain, perlin-noise

We use a Perlin noise function to generate a height map (which could be treated as a greyscale bitmap image).

Are there any techniques to go in the other direction? I have the bitmap and I want to determine the perlin noise function(s) and their parameters (amplitude, octaves, frequency,etc) that would generate it.

I'm assuming that for complex images, several perlin functions would be necessary - either layer the results on top of one another or use block by block.

Comment: that would be extremely complicated, essentially you attempt to reverse engineer Perlin noise, which is about as easy as coding and Nintendo 64 emulator I would think! it depends how many octaves there are etc as well. The more there are, the more difficult. No one has done it because it would seem the uses of something like that would be really 0 for anyone normally

Answer (score 0):

You could get frequency domain information of your 2D function (bitmap) using 2D discrete fourier transformation (FFT). There are several mathematical libraries implementing it. On the other hand the result won't be exactly what you are looking for because perlin noise is compiled from random noise functions, but fourier transformation decompose your map into multiple sinusoids with different amplitude and frequency. An explicite perlin noise decomposition would have multiple solutions, since you can get the same composit noise function from different random noise functions.